# What's the easiest way to get a list from a Flowable in java?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

My database returns a Flowable like so:

```
Flowable<List<Users>> users = MyActivity.myDatabase.myDAO().getUsers();
```

I would like to quickly and easily convert it to a list so I can count it, iterate through it and perhaps pass it as an ArrayList. What's the best way to do that using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a blocking call to actually retrieve the values. However, it's not clear from the question whether you are expecting a single list of users or a list of user lists.

If you are expecting a single `List<Users>`, you can do this:

```
List<Users> usersList = users.blockingFirst();
```

If you are expecting a list of user lists, you would need to do something like this:

```
List<List<Users>> userLists = users.toList().blockingGet();
```

In either case, if you specifically need an `ArrayList`, you will have to construct one and copy over the elements, as there is no telling exactly what kind of `List` implementation the above codes return. (You can just do, for instance, `new ArrayList<>(users.blockingFirst())` in the first case and something similar in the second.)